# Replica had multiple failures in API call: IStatelessServiceInstance.Open()

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I'm stuck with the following exception from the Service Fabric Explorer:

```
Unhealthy event: SourceId='System.RA', Property='ReplicaOpenStatus', HealthState='Warning', ConsiderWarningAsError=false.
Replica had multiple failures in API call: IStatelessServiceInstance.Open(); Error = System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException (-2146232828)
Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.ConfigureBuilder.Invoke(Object instance, IApplicationBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.BuildApplication()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilder.Build()
   at FRSecure.AssessmentDesigner.Web.WebHostBuilderHelper.GetWebHost(IWebHostBuilder webHostBuilder, String protocol, String port, String environment) in D:\a\1\s\web_assessmentdesigner\WebHostBuilderHelper.cs:line 16
   at web_assessmentdesigner.WebHostingService.Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Communication.Runtime.ICommunicationListener.OpenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in D:\a\1\s\web_assessmentdesigner\WebHostingService.cs:line 75
   at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Runtime.StatelessServiceInstanceAdapter.d__13.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Runtime.StatelessServiceInstanceAdapter.d__0.MoveNext()
```

Here is what I know:

1. App installs and runs fine on a local cluster, but not on Azure.
2. The App consists of a stateless api and a stateful service. The stateful service starts up fine. The stateless goes into a failed state after about 2 minutes.

My question is this: How, or where can I obtain more information about the underlying exception? The service is failing before it has started so my logging is not yet available. I see nothing in Diagnostics on the portal.  What is the best way to troubleshoot something like this when it cannot be replicated locally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have enabled the Event provider `Microsoft-ServiceFabric` (`Guid = "cbd93bc2-71e5-4566-b3a7-595d8eeca6e8"`) to send events to Diagnostics then you should be able to see some Events written relating to this, the class `StatelessServiceInstanceAdapter` which is calling your `WebHostBuilderHelper` should emit an event  that says something like `Got exception when opening communication listeners - XXX` when it runs into the exception above, this could potentially hold more information on why your service fails.

You could also simply wrap your `WebHostBuilderHelper.GetWebHost(...)` implementation in a try/catch and logging any exceptions caught to your `ServiceEventSource`. The exception happens when the service tries to open the listener, but it is unclear from the above why.

Comment: Diagnostics seemed to me as the right tool for this, so I'm glad you confirmed that. I think there must be something wrong the setup of the Diagnostics. I have the provider you mention. Should I see something in the portal: Monitor->Diagnostics Log? I have updated my template to support diagnostic with information from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-diagnostics-how-to-setup-wad

Comment: If you have added the ``EtwManifestProviderConfiguration`` for ``cbd93bc2-71e5-4566-b3a7-595d8eeca6e8`` then you should see those events in diagnostics. If you suspect there is something wrong with your Diagnostics setup you could try to Enable Streaming Traces in Visual Studio for your cluster and then look at one of the nodes as you redeploy your service and see if you can catch the event, and hopefully the exception information attached to it there.

Comment: I realized there was log information stored in the Diagnostics storage table. For some reason I was expecting it would show up in "Diagnostics" on the portal. I was able to view the storage table from Visual Studio by connecting to the remote cluster.

Comment: Yes, that's a also a way to view it, all the events that are sent via the VM extension ends up there. Did you enable Log Analytics for Service Fabric for your cluster? It is a little tricky to set it up right, but once running it's great for finding issues... Did you find the problem in your logs?

Comment: Yes,turned out to be a network connectivity issue when the stateless service was starting and setting up Authentication to a sql database. When you can see the actual issue, it is easy to address...